# Animated sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make animated sticky navigation that slides in at the top of the page after it is scrolled down 955px, and slides back up if the page is scrolled to less than 955px.
I managed to animate the first step by setting top to 0 and margin-top to -172px in css and animating top by 172px in jquery, but I don't know how to reverse this after the page is scrolled back up.

html:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="#torte">Torte</a>
        <a href="#kolaci">Kolači</a>
        <a href="#napici">Napici</a>
        <a href="#slatka-peciva">Slatka Peciva</a>
        <a href="#jela">Jela</a>
        <a href="#slana-peciva">Slana Peciva</a>
        <a href="#oblogu">O blogu</a>
        <a href="#contact">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="#ostalo">Ostalo</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Css:

```
header{
    height: 125px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -172px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

jQuery:

```
/* sticky navigation, active class */
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 955) {
        $('header').animate({'top':172});
        $('section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 50) {
                $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    } else {
        /*
        code for the slide up animation goes here
        */
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
    }

}).scroll();
```

How do I reverse the animation after the page is scrolled up again?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's quite simple. Just added .stop() in front of animate for slide in animation, and for slide up I used the same line of code and then set the top to 0 to reverse it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (windscroll >= 955) {
    $('header').stop().animate({'top':172});
    $('section').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 50) {
            $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
            $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
        }
    });

} else {
    $('header').stop().animate({'top':0});
    $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
}
```

}).scroll();